# How to test if a conditional inside a function is executed in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

how would i test if a conditional value inside a function is executed in jasmine.

ex:

```
onDestroy(){
   if(this.somethingExists){
      callSomeFunction();
   }
}
```

in Jasmine how would i test if a conditional in this case the if statement, is executed, inside of the onDestroy function

Comment: Where is `callSomeFunction` defined? -- Consider using a spy https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html

Comment: yes i am using spy but how? callSomeFunction() is the method of an object instantiated from a node_module package

Comment: Spy on the prototype? `const spy = spyOn(module.prototype, 'callSomeFunction')`?